# Unable To Run Access Report With Column Name Which Has Special Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run a report in Access that references a poorly named column: Vendor#. For those of you not familiar with Access: '#' is a reserved keyword with special meaning. I've been trying to run the report and every time I do a popup appears asking for a value for the column: in other words it keeps seeing it as a variable name. I've tried a number of variations on the name including: [Vendor#], 'Vendor#', ['Vendor#']. I tried an Alias but then I encountered the same issue in the where clause referencing the Alias. No I can't change the schema to rename the column to something more appropriate. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_Vendors
WHERE ((dbo_Vendors.[Vendor#]) = [Forms]![frm_Report_Vendor]![VendorNumber])
```

Comment: I have just tested with a linked sql server table having a column called Vendor#. I can create a report and it runs correctly. What query / sql are you using?

Comment: Yes it is for a linked table. Can you show the query you are running so I have an idea for the syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the query: SELECT * FROM dbo_Vendors WHERE ((dbo_Vendors.[Vendor#]) = [Forms]![frm_Report_Vendor]![VendorNumber])

Comment: Yes it is open; I open the report and enter the vendor number and in theory it should get picked up.

Comment: Ultimately the query will run and the report will popup after I close the pop up asking for a value for Vendor#.

Comment: Can you save the query and test that the query runs? I suspect that you may have a misspelled form reference, because I have tested the whole scenario and it works for me. I do not think the report has anything to do with it.

Comment: Ok; thanks. I'd tested it before; but I'll test it again. Just to clarify; when you ran it you used the following syntax: dbo_Vendors.[Vendor#] ?

Comment: It was the query. It took some time to figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you are using SQL server, I reckon you would be better using a "Pass-Through Query", the column name then shouldn't cause any complications and you should also see better performance from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested with a linked sql server table having a column called Vendor#. I can create a report and it runs correctly.

Can you save the query and test that the query runs? I suspect that you may have a misspelled form reference, because I have tested the whole scenario and it works for me. I do not think the report has anything to do with it.

Comment: This was a mistake on my part and the report wasn't related.